# (x,y) can be expressed as a differentiable function of (w,z)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider equations $$ \exp(w) + x = y + \exp(z)$$
and $$\cos(w) + \sin(x) + \tan(y) = z + 1$$ 
Show that near $(x, y,w, z) = (0, 0, 0, 0)$, $(x, y)$ can be expressed as a differentiable function of $(w,z)$. Also compute $\frac{\delta x}{\delta w}(0,0)$ and $\frac{\delta y}{\delta w}(0,0)$.

Comment: Check out the implicit function theorem.

Comment: implicit differentiation after invoking the implicit function thm or since you just want the values of the derivatives at (0,0) expand a few terms of the macluain series, differentiate and substitute.

Answer (score 2):

You have two equations $$\begin{cases} f(x,y,z,w) := \exp(w) + x - y - \exp(z)= 0 \\
                                       g(x,y,z,w) := \cos(w) + \sin(x) + \tan(y) - z - 1 = 0
\end{cases}$$
and the point $(0,0,0,0)$ satisfies both. If you want to express $(x,y)$ as function of $(z,w)$ (near $(0,0)$) you have to write the Jacobian matrix 
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
f_x & f_y & f_z & f_w \\
g_x & g_y & g_z & g_w \\
\end{array} \right)$$
and check that the $2 \times 2$ minor $\det \left( \begin{array}{cc}
f_x & f_y \\
g_x & g_y \end{array} \right)$ is not zero at $(0,0,0,0)$. In your case such minor is $\det \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 \\
\cos(x) & \frac{1}{\cos^2(y)} \\ \end{array} \right)$ so it is indeed different from $0$ at $(0,0,0,0)$. So due to the implicit function theorem you can express $(x,y)$ as function of $(z,w)$ near $(0,0)$.

For the partial derivatives observe that $$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
f_x & f_y \\
g_x & g_y \\ \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
x_w \\
y_w \\ \end{array} \right) = - \left( \begin{array}{c}
f_w \\
g_w \\ \end{array} \right) \, .$$
So you can find the values of $x_w,y_w$ at $(0,0)$ by the usual Cramer's rules from the values of the partial derivatives of $f,g$ at $(0,0,0,0)$.